# Need help debugging my Binary Clock

Tags: c++, led

I have tried everything but I can't get my binary clock to display correctly. The diagram and code are here: [Binary Clock | Electronics Lab](https://123d.circuits.io/circuits/1586601-binary-clock).

The hardware is based off this (it also explains the process that my program is trying to do): [DIY: Binary Clock with Arduino](http://www.danielandrade.net/2008/07/15/binary-clock-with-arduino/). The problems lie in a, probably, simple error as my variable `tempTime`, which is used to convert the individual digits to their binary equivalent, does not change when I tell it to. All this occurs in the display function. (Sorry, I'm new Here and only a high school student)

While debugging it I realized that the only problem is the variable `tempTime` - the hardware and other functions work as they were intended. 
Can anyone help? (Sorry if this is not very well documented).

```
    int digitPins[4][4] = {{13,6,-1,-1},{12,7,3,1},{11,8,4,-1},{10,9,5,2}};
int time[4] = {0,0,0,0};
int steps[4]={1,2,4,8};
int tempTime = 0;
void setup(){
  for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
    for(int y =0; y<4; y++){
    pinMode(digitPins[x][y],OUTPUT);
    }
  }
    Serial.begin(9600);
    convertHour(12);
    convertMinute(57);
    Serial.println("The time is:");

  for(int z = 0; z < 4; z++){
    if(z == 2){
    Serial.print(":");
    }
  Serial.print(time[z]);
  }
  display();
}
void loop(){

}
void display(){
  int displayer[13] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
/*
0 - Hour
1 - Hour
2 - Minute
3 - Minute
4 - Hour(Total)
5 - Minute(Total)
*/

  int counter1 = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){ //Loop for the individual digits
    tempTime = time[i];
    if(tempTime >= 10){
    tempTime = tempTime % 10;
    }
    Serial.print("\nBegining new iteration i = ");
    Serial.print("\nStarting with digit: ");
    Serial.print(tempTime);
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.println("");
    for(int j = 3; j >= 0; j--){//Loop to determin the arrangement
      if(time[i]/steps[j] >= 1 && steps[j] > 0 && digitPins[i][j] > 0){
        Serial.print("\n");
        Serial.print(time[i]);
        Serial.print("/");
        Serial.print(steps[j]);
        Serial.print(" = ");
        Serial.print(time[i]/steps[j]);
        tempTime =tempTime - (time[i]*steps[j]);
        displayer[counter1] = digitPins[i][j];
        Serial.print("\nAdded: ");
        Serial.print(digitPins[i][j]);
        counter1++;
      }
    }

  }
  clear();
  for(int a = 0; a < 13; a++){
  digitalWrite(displayer[a],HIGH);
  }
}
void clear(){
  for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
    for(int y =0; y<4; y++){
    digitalWrite(digitPins[x][y],LOW);
    }
  }
}
  void convertHour(int value){
    int digits[] = {0,0};
    if(value >= 10){
        debug("Bigger than 10");
        if(value >= 20){
            digits[0] = 2;  
        }else{
            digits[0] = 1;
        }
    }
    digits[1] = value - (digits[0] * 10);
    //String hour = digits[0]+""+digits[1];
    //Serial.print(digits[0]);
    //Serial.print(digits[1]);
    time[0] = digits[0];
    time[1] = digits[1];
  }
void convertMinute(int value){
  int digits[2] = {0,0};
  int val = value;
  if(value >= 10){
    digits[0] = val/10;
  }
  digits[1] = value - (digits[0] * 10);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.print(digits[0]);
  Serial.print(digits[1]);
  time[2] = digits[0];
  time[3] = digits[1];
}
  void debug(String value){
    boolean de = true;
    if(de){
    Serial.println(value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Serial and LED on the same pin?

Comment: Calculate the power requirements for all these LEDs (and 120 ohm). Will the Uno be able to deliver that?

Comment: We need more information.  What should it do? What does it do? What have you tried?

Comment: Very Sorry wrote that post in a hurry. The hardware is based off this (it also explains the proccess that my program is trying to do): http://www.danielandrade.net/2008/07/15/binary-clock-with-arduino/ The problems lie in  a probably simple error as my variable tempTime which is used to convert the individual digits to their binary equivalent does not change when I tell it to. All this occurs in the display function. (Sorry New Here and only a highschool student)

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the code into it please? This is looking like a link-only question. Format the code using the code formatting markdown (four leading spaces). For help see [Markdown help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You should be able to do this by selecting the code and pressing `Ctrl+K` to have your browser do this for you. If that link goes down the question, and any following answer, will be meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your “Loop to determin the arrangement”, you are erroneously using
`time[i]` in several places where you mean `tempTime`. Also, to update
`tempTime` you only have to subtract `steps[j]`. With these fixes, your
loop becomes:

```
for(int j = 3; j >= 0; j--){//Loop to determin the arrangement
  if(tempTime/steps[j] >= 1 && steps[j] > 0 && digitPins[i][j] > 0){
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print(tempTime);
    Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(steps[j]);
    Serial.print(" = ");
    Serial.print(tempTime/steps[j]);
    tempTime = tempTime - steps[j];
    displayer[counter1] = digitPins[i][j];
    Serial.print("\r\nAdded: ");
    Serial.print(digitPins[i][j]);
    counter1++;
  }
}
```

Now, if you learn a little bit about how binary numbers work, and about
the binary operators in C and C++, you can rewrite your loop in a
simpler form:

```
for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {
  int weight = 1 << j;      // 2 raised to the power j
  if (tempTime & weight) {  // if bit j of tempTime is set
    displayer[counter1++] = digitPins[i][j];
    Serial.print("Added bit ");
    Serial.print(j);
    Serial.print(", weight ");
    Serial.print(weight);
    Serial.print(", output ");
    Serial.println(digitPins[i][j]);
  }
}
```

As a side note, it is considered good practice to print a new line at
the *end* of each string you print (using `println()`), rather than at
the beginning.

**Edit**: As your `display()` function is way too complex for what it
does, I did not resist the temptation to simplify it:

```
void display() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4 && digitPins[i][j] >= 0; j++)
      digitalWrite(digitPins[i][j], time[i] & (1<<j));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm relatively new to c++ with a background in js and php, still trying to get the hang of it.

Comment: Well, the bitwise operators of C and C++ are the same you already know from JavaScript and PHP.